# Cucumber scenario assert condition in DataTable

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have the following scenario in Cucumber-jvm and wondering whats the best way of writing this.

```
Given I create a process
When I execute the following tasks with parameters:
|Task Name| param1 | param2| param3|
...
Then each task should have outcomes:
|Task Name| outcome1 | outcome2| outcome3|
```

Whats the best way of approaching this?

I need to execute the When Task1, Then Task1 followed by When Task2 Then Task2 etc due to state information being lost when the next task is started. Instead of invoking all of the When Task1,2,3 first followed by the Then Task1,2,3 first.

There will also be a lot of tasks +50 so splitting this into separate steps is not ideal.

I could merge the When/Then into one step but that doesn't seem right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a Scenario Outline. This will run each task as a scenario in itself.

To avoid the `Given step` being repeated you can setup a static boolean variable in your step definition java and check it as a flag.

```
Scenario Outline:
Given I create a process
When I execute the following task <TaskName> with parameters:
|<Parameter1>|<Parameter2>|<Parameter3>|
Then each task <TaskName> should have outcomes:
|<Outcome1>|<Outcome2>|<Outcome3>|

Examples:
|TaskName|Parameter1|Parameter2|Parameter3|Outcome1|Outcome2|Outcome3|
|task1|t1param1|t1param2|t1param3|t1out1|t1out2|t1out3|
|task2|t2param1|t2param2|t2param3|t2out1|t2out2|t2out3|
.......
```

In case you have variable number of parameters and outcomes, modify them by using a symbol delimited string. You can use the `@Transform annotation` in the step definition to get an object of parameters or outcomes.

```
Scenario Outline:

Given I create a process
When I execute the following task <TaskName> with parameters <parameters>
Then each task <TaskName> should have outcomes <outcomes>

Examples:
| TaskName | Parameters | Outcomes |
| task1 | t1param1,t1param2,t1param3| t1out1,t1out2,t1out3 |
| task2 | t2param1,t2param2,t2param3| t2out1,t2out2,t2out3 |
.......
```

If there is any dependency of of one task on the outcome of the other task then you have to be careful in how you handle them. You could even add a reset step like, killing current process etc, after your current Then step if required in any of the tasks.

---

Last scenario ---This is a big hack dependent on the scenario id remaining same.
Add the count of scenarios in the example table for the last step as below.

```
Scenario Outline:

    Given I create a process
    When I execute the following task <TaskName> with parameters <parameters>
    Then each task <TaskName> should have outcomes <outcomes>
    ***And Last step to run for last scenario 3***

    Examples:
    | TaskName | Parameters | Outcomes |
    | task1 | t1param1,t1param2,t1param3| t1out1,t1out2,t1out3 |
    | task2 | t2param1,t2param2,t2param3| t2out1,t2out2,t2out3 |
    | task3 | t3param1,t3param2,t3param3| t3out1,t3out2,t3out3 |


Include in StepDefinition.java

private Scenario scenario;

@Before
public void before(Scenario sce) {
    this.scenario = sce;
    System.out.println("SCENARIO ID -- " +scenario.getId());
}
```

You will get a string like for scenario outline - `**feature-description ; scenariooutline-description ; example-description ; rownumber + 1**`. For example -- `validating-sample;so1;se1;2`. This will be for the first row of the examples table.

For scenario outline case you can split with delimiter ";" and use the last part after subtracting 1. Put this logic in a method `getCurrentExamplesRow()`

```
@Then("^Last step to run for last scenario (\\d+)$")
public void lastStep(int size) {

    // Will be called only for last scenario in examples... 
    if(size==getCurrentExamplesRow()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper, the tasks I'm executing are dependent on each other and have to be executed in the order specified. I don't think this will be a issue as it will be a stateless call to invoke the task.

Comment: I will test this out and respond shortly

Comment: Is there a way to break out of a scenario outline? Ie to execute a single then statement after the examples iteration?

Comment: Each line in the examples table is run as a self-contained scenario in itself. Do you want to run the Then step only for the last scenario in the examples table or for any scenario depending on some logic?

Comment: Just for the last step to assert the process has finished and to reset the static variable as I need 2 scenario outlines for slightly different task orders.

Comment: Tried it once... Is a big hack... Added it in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the example Grasshopper, I've decided to add a new field to indicate if the a task is the last or not instead of doing this hack as I don't like having the number of tasks hard coded into the features file. If I have to hardcode something then I think it would be better to make it meaningful instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by having this step

```
When I execute the following tasks with parameters:
|Task Name| param1 | param2| param3|
...
```

This is a really poor way to use Cucumber. Instead you should be replacing each instance of this step with a single step of the format

```
When I xxx
```

Your task is then to find replacements (names) for xxx. These names should describe what the combined effect of executing all your tasks are.

It really doesn't matter what tasks you have or how many tasks you have, you can always find a name that encapsulates the whole lot.

Now the list of tasks you have perform you newly named task (the HOW), can be defined further down your stack. This could be in your step definitions, helper methods for step definitions, or better yet in your actual code.

The process of finding this single name is called abstraction. Its something you use every day - you make a cup of tea, not

```
fill the kettle with 350ml of cold water
switch of the kettle just before its boiled
pour 5ml of water into each cup to warm them
switch on the kettle until its boiled
... 
...
zzzzzz
```

What you doing in your scenario is just as silly as saying to someone all that stuff instead of `make some tea`!

The whole point of Cucumber using natural language is to allow scenario writers to use the power of natural language to write things that are simple and expressive. Every time you let a detail of HOW something is done slip into a scenario you are failing to use language effectively.

Comment: Thanks for explaining abstraction for me!

Comment: Why would I want to increase the maintenance overhead of writing all of the tasks on Java when it's generic enough to be in a data table. This also allows all scenarios to be tested and changed easily. I don't support your answer or view.

Comment: when you write data tables in scenarios you are increasing maintenance overhead. Data tables that aren't checked by code, are maintained by hand and are not explained are error prone. This hurts you when something breaks or you need to change something. Every detail of how something is done that is in a scenario has to be somewhere else as well, so you end up with two definitions of things those in your scenarios and those in your code/step definitions. All of this creates greater maintenance costs.

Comment: When people take time to reply to your questions, you could at least by civil even if you don't agree with the answer. Sarcasm isn't an appropriate response. Having never met you I have no idea about your level of understanding of abstraction. All I have to go on is your post and that indicates that you are not applying abstraction to this particular problem. My 10 years of experience using Cucumber suggests that a solution to your problem is to apply abstraction to your scenarios. Its fine by me if you don't like my answer, but there is no need to be rude.